# Can a computer display output without a Vesa/VGA compatible card

Tags: graphics-card, vga, vesa

A while back I got into an argument with someone over whether a computer without either a discrete or integrated graphics solution (Ryzen in this situation) could display output from the motherboard's inbuilt HDMI connection.

I took the position of 'yes' with the thought that software rendering is possible. Surely one could use the CPU to send the correct signals to the HDMI connector without a VGA card.

I've tried googling this problem, but unfortunately most questions asked are by people who are for people who are new to computing so the answers are not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely one could use the CPU to send the correct signals to the HDMI connector without a VGA card.

This is called "bit-banging" - essentially the CPU is constantly changing an I/O register to create a signal.

It's possible and has been done with very low speed interfaces, like serial ports.  The old Commodore 64 pretty much did this with its implementation of RS-232 and bus it used to talk to printers and disk drives.  RS-232 couldn't go any faster than 2400 bits per second (2.4Kbit/sec).

But HDMI is a very, very fast interface.  For example, HDMI 2.0 has a speed of 18Gbps.  That means 18 billion times a second, the CPU would have to do something to modulate a signal.

Given that even your fastest CPUs are about 3GHz, and while that means the cycle time for instructions is 1/3,000,000,000 -

- almost all CPU instructions take more than one cycle
- I/O instructions are "serializing" (because they have to be done in order) so advanced CPU features like speculation don't help.
- Because stuff has to be done in order down 1 pipe, multiple CPUs do not help.
- I/O instructions don't interact with memory or registers so caching/MMX/SSE/AVX/EVEX won't do anything except help determine what you want to send down the pipe.

so I don't really think there is a way you can "bit-bang" at 18GHz with modern x86 CPUs and you could not even do 3Ghz.  Maybe a really really low refresh rate if the HDMI interface doesn't have a minimum speed.

But you can see why specialized hardware drives the interface.

In any event you still need some sort of minimum hardware for a connection as your CPU is connected to a bus and that hardware has to talk the same "language" or protocol as that bus to interact with the CPU.  For old systems like the Commodore 64 and its ilk above, it had devices like the "Versatile Interface Adapter" or "Complex Interface Adapter" - the CPU would read/write to this chip to get the state of "ports" (it was connected to and appeared on CPU bus) and the chip would have a physical connection to pins out of physical ports in the back or slots in the motherboard.

For modern x86 CPUs the closest you have now is PCI-E, and PCI-E controllers are built into CPUs now, but were part of the chipset.  So you would still need something that takes PCI-E signals and converts them to the HDMI signals at the very least.

[VGA is a different matter](http://neil.franklin.ch/Projects/SoftVGA/) though.

Comment: This was a fantastic answer. Thanks so much for explaining it clearly!

Answer (score 1):

No, it can not. Without an inbuilt graphics unit there is no physical connection to those ports. You need some kind of hardware that is connected to that port for the port to actually be usable.

Answer (score 1):

### I think your friend wins the bet.

Two things are required to output actual video via an HDMI or other physical interface:

1. Generating consecutive video frames
2. Transmitting the frames via the video connector.

**It's the task of communicating with the actual hardware port that a CPU cannot reasonably do by itself.**

Given you expect *actual output* via the HDMI port, here are two reasons this isn't done solely with a CPU:

1. Rendering each frame of video output is computationally intensive in a repetitive way. A CPU *could* do the work, but this would significantly hamper its ability to do its "day job", making for a slow system. GPUs are purpose built for this type of work.
2. Converting the digital representation of a video frame into the signals required to transmit it out a physical port requires hardware custom to that port. CPUs are meant to work in many different systems and don't have control over the physical video ports they might be expected to work with. This makes it impossible for a pure CPU to handle end-to-end the task of generating video frames *and* outputting it via a physical port. Even modern CPUs that include a GPU built-in depend on additional components provided on the motherboard to output video, and technically these two pieces together form a graphics card.

Obviously the CPU can do task 1, but it's task 2 that requires additional hardware to accomplish. In modern computers, that's the graphics adapter.